# How does health coverage work after being laid off?

Tags: united-states, health, layoff, insurance

I recently got laid off from my job in the USA like many other people. I have had health insurance coverage through my employer, and so I called my insurance today to ask for a loss of coverage letter. But I was informed that my coverage is still active.
Normally, my premium would be subtracted from my paycheck like everyone else. So how am I covered if I'm not making any payments? Or do I have to pay in one way or another?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107452/discussion-on-question-by-blueseal-how-does-health-coverage-work-after-being-lai).

Comment: Such health insurance questions are on-topic at https://money.stackexchange.com. See [U.S. health insurance questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-insurance+united-states).

Answer (score 2):

> I recently got laid off from my job in the USA like many other people. I have had health insurance coverage through my employer, and so I called my insurance today to ask for a loss of coverage letter. But I was informed that my coverage is still active.

You may still have coverage through your employer through the end of the month, but you should double check with the benefits department before you leave your job.

You should be offered an opportunity to purchase COBRA (Consolidated Omnibus Budget Reconciliation Act, the name of the Act that set it up) health insurance: https://www.healthcare.gov/unemployed/cobra-coverage/

If you are not offered COBRA or chose not to take it, you can read up at the US government's healthcare website on next steps: https://www.healthcare.gov/unemployed/coverage/

Answer (score -1):

Here is some definitive (US) information:

https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/cobra-continuing-health-insurance-after-job-loss.html

*(Fair warning:  "it isn't pretty ...")*